# Empty copy of Pandas DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe, indexing

I'm looking for an efficient idiom for creating a new Pandas `DataFrame` with the same columns and types as an existing `DataFrame`, but with no rows.  The following works, but is presumably much less efficient than it could be, because it has to create a long indexing structure and then evaluate it for each row.  I'm assuming that's `O(n)` in the number of rows, and I would like to find an `O(1)` solution (that's not too bad to look at).

```
out = df.loc[np.repeat(False, df.shape[0])].copy()
```

I have the `copy()` in there because I honestly have no idea under what circumstances I'm getting a copy or getting a view into the original.

For comparison in R, a nice idiom is to do `df[0,]`, because there's no zeroth row.  `df[NULL,]` also works.

Comment: ``pd.DataFrame([], columns=df.columns).astype(df.dtypes)``?

Comment: what's the use case?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the equivalent in pandas would be slicing using `iloc`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [0,1,2,3], 'B' : [4,5,6,7]})
print(df1)
   A  B
0  0  4
1  1  5
2  2  6
3  3  7
```

---

```
df1 = df.iloc[:0].copy()

print(df1)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [A, B]
Index: []
```

Comment: Aha - I was trying to use `x.loc[:0]`, but with `iloc` it works quite well, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Df1 the existing DataFrame:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'x1':[1,2,3], 'x2':[4,5,6]})
```

Df2 the new, based on the columns in `df1`:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({}, columns=df1.columns)
```

For setting the dtypes of the different columns:

```
for x in df1.columns:
    df2[x]=df2[x].astype(df1[x].dtypes.name)
```

Comment: That just has the same column names, but doesn't carry over other properties like data types.

Comment: you're right. There seems no solution inside pd.DataFrame itself, only if you are certain  that all columns will be the same type you can do something like `df2 = pd.DataFrame({}, dtype='int', columns=df1.columns)`. Otherwise there is a hack around looping over the columns which I added to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

#### Update no rows

Use [reindex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html?highlight=reindex#pandas-dataframe-reindex):

```
dfcopy = pd.DataFrame().reindex(columns=df.columns)
print(dfcopy)
```

Output:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [a, b, c, d, e]
Index: []
```

---

We can use [reindex_like](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex_like.html#pandas-dataframe-reindex-like).

```
dfcopy = pd.DataFrame().reindex_like(df)
```

MCVE:

```
#Create dummy source dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(25).reshape(5,-1), index=[*'ABCDE'], columns=[*'abcde'])

dfcopy = pd.DataFrame().reindex_like(df)
print(dfcopy)
```

Output:

```
    a   b   c   d   e
A NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
B NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
C NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
D NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
E NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Comment: Doesn't reindex_like use both columns and index? The question asked for no rows, but I think this will return the same shape as df.

Comment: Yes... it does the same shape.

Comment: Right, this doesn't return what I'm looking for, I'm wanting a zero-row df.

Comment: @KenWilliams See update using `pd.DataFrame.reindex`

Comment: That can get the right number of rows & columns, but the information about column data types and anything else kept at the `DataFrame` class level is lost.

Answer (score 0):

Please deep copy original `df` and `drop index`.

```
#df1=(df.copy(deep=True)).drop(df.index)#If df is small
df1=df.drop(df.index).copy()#If df is large and dont want to copy and discard
```

Comment: Thanks, but if `df` is large that's a lot of copying just to throw it away.

Comment: @Ken Williams, you still can `df1=df.drop(df.index).copy()`. That way you dont copy whole and discard especially if the datframe is big